# mysql query to find that time is between from and to time

Tags: mysql, time

I have a **from_time** an **to_time** in my table.
one of the record is from_time: 19:00:00 and to_time: 01:30:00
if user select **12:30 AM or 11:00 PM**. 
how do i correctly find that it is between from_time and to_time.

Mysql query i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  '19:00:00' >= from_time  and '19:00:00' <= to_time
```

is not working.

Comment: Why are you using **19:00:00** in your query ?

Comment: save the time as integer using timestamp and then you can select properly

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You used value instead of column name

You can use as below query. You can change value as per your need.

**Change Time value as per your need first.**

First Option with `Where`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  from_time >= '00:00:00'  and to_time <= '23:59:59'
```

Second option is `between`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  from_time between '00:00:00'  and '23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not show where the selected time is coming from. Is it in a column, is it something that the user sets in the SQL or is it sent through code?

If the time is set in the SQL then the way to do this is as follows:

```
SET @mytime := '19:00:00';
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(@mytime AS TIME) BETWEEN from_time AND to_time;
```

where @mytime is the user set variable and assuming that from_time and to_time are time format.

My test table for the above was as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `timetest` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_time` time DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

with test data as:

```
INSERT INTO `timetest` (`id`, `from_time`, `to_time`) VALUES
(1, '09:00:00', '11:00:00'),
(2, '06:30:00', '14:00:00'),
(3, '14:29:10', '16:12:18'),
(4, '09:11:17', '23:00:01'),
(5, '18:00:00', '23:59:59'),
(6, '01:12:00', '11:59:44');
```

Answer (score 0):

For to_times which go over midnight you could add 24hours and then test. For example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(from_time time, to_time time);
insert into t values
('18:00:00','20:00:00'),
('18:00:00','01:00:00'),
('16:00:00','18:00:00');



select from_time,to_time,
         case when  '19:00:00' between 
                from_time and
         if(to_time < from_time, 
         addtime(to_time,'24:00:00'),
          to_time) 
          then 'true'
         else 'false'
         end as truefalse
from t;
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| from_time | to_time  | truefalse |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 18:00:00  | 20:00:00 | true      |
| 18:00:00  | 01:00:00 | true      |
| 16:00:00  | 18:00:00 | false     |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```